# Set cover problem NP completeness

Tags: optimization, np-complete

I have a quick question about Set cover problem. In Wikipedia, < https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem >, they are saying "The decision version of set covering is NP-complete, and the optimization/search version of set cover is NP-hard". What is the decision version and what is the optimization version? I am really confused here. I used to learn that set cover is an NP-hard problem. Many thanks!

Comment: The page you cite explains this in detail in the fourth paragraph, starting "More formally ... ."  Can you explain what part of that paragraph is giving you difficulty?

Comment: This CS Stack reference question might be of use to you.  https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9556/what-is-the-definition-of-p-np-np-complete-and-np-hard